# Geometric sequence woes

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following geometric sequence $c^2, c^5, c^8$

we know that r is defined as $$r=\frac{a_{i+1}}{a_i}$$

where $r$ is constant across the geometric set!

What I have

$${c^5\over c^2} = c^3 = r$$

so the $n^{th}$ term should be $$a_n=c^2(c^3)^{n-1}$$

this is given that $a_n = a_1(r)^{n-1}$ but my text book states that the correct answer is just $ a_n = c^{3n-1} $ what am I missing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing nothing: $ 2+3(n-1)=3n-1$.

Comment: holy snap how i missed that in multiplying exponents!  that becomes `3n-3+2`!  or `3n-1` :)!